# asp.net core get checkbox value in controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="fruits" value="5">
```

How to get the checkbox value in MVC controller if the checkbox is checked?

Comment: How are you submitting the values? Are the inputs part of a form?

Answer (score 0):

So you dont get if its checked or not but you can get the value of the fruits input as follow:

```
checkbox.text = Request.Form["fruits"];
```